# errors am getting in submission xcode app

Tags: ios, xcode

1) iPhone/iPod Touch: info.plist: unable to verify icon dimensions, no icon found. you must define CFBundleicons,CFBundleIconfiles or provide a default Icon.png that is 57 by 57.
2)Application failed codedesign verification.The signature was invalid,contains disallowd entitlements, or it was not signed with in iphone distribution Certficate.
I am geting above errors when i want to submit app from App Loader.

Comment: And you can see the icon, it has 57x57 dimensions, the release build also succeeds ?

Comment: i have placeed icon 57x57 in resourese/images..and my build succeeds and tested on device as well. Any help..

Comment: make sure you are testing the release configuration, it must be signed with distribution profile (in general you can launch it from xcode with the release configuration and development certificate selected), check `entitlement.plist` if it's used.

Comment: what is entitlement.plist...I am new....pls help me to get on..

Comment: A-live: First one i have solve..2 one..can u help me to fix......

Comment: A-live: Under Provisional profile/Distribution  certificates, My distribution certificate method is Adhoc. should i create another certificate..? If needs, how can i override first one..

Comment: I believe you need to create and use the AppStore-method profile, please follow the instructions carefully: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/SubmitYourApp/SubmitYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011375-CH7-SW1

Comment: a valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain. i have created new distributoin cert..then am getting this warning..

Comment: There must be a problem of how you created it, you can try to remove the certificates from keychain and redownload it, if it doesn't work i'd remove the private key used for certificates and start the provisioning from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

To submit your app to apstore you have build your app using Distribution Provisional profiles

To create a distribution provisioning profile . . .

1. Log in to the iOS Provisioning Portal from the Member Center.
2. Select Provisioning in the sidebar.
3. Select the Distribution tab.
4. Click New Profile.
5. Select App Store as the distribution method.
   [image: See Image]
6. Enter a profile name.
7. Confirm that your distribution certificate is displayed.
8. Click Submit.

better to look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/SubmitYourApp/SubmitYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011375-CH7-SW1)